Facet plot with coord_fixed(), but also labelling each x-axis separately
I want to make a facet plot in ggplot, but I want the aspect-ratio to be fixed (1:1) and also label each x axis. Here is in example:
data <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
data$col <- rpois(nrow(data), lambda = 10)
data <- rbind(cbind(data, "type" = "a"), cbind(data, "type" = "b"))

ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = col)) +
  labs(x = "very long label of x") +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 2) +
  coord_fixed()

This gives this result:

But I want the label of the x axis under each plot. I wanted to use scales = "free" with the hope of getting what I want, but I get an error:
Error in `draw_panels()`:
! `facet_wrap()` can't use free scales with `coord_fixed()`

Can anybody help me? I could use grid.extra to combine two separate plots, but this makes additional work again when trying to share the legend. Is there an easy fix?

TBMK, the only option to get an axis title for each panel would be to combine two separate plots for which I would go for patchwork as it allows for easy collecting of the guides. Some more work is to be done to get rid of the duplicated y axes if this is required:
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)

data |>
  split(~type) |>
  purrr::imap(\(x, y) {
    remove_y <- if (y != "a") {
      scale_y_continuous(
        breaks = NULL, name = NULL
      )
    }
    ggplot() +
      geom_tile(data = x, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = col)) +
      labs(x = "very long label of x") +
      facet_wrap(~type) +
      coord_fixed() +
      remove_y
  }) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")


